# Get the optimizations from retail build into debug build

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, debugging

I have a function when unit tested takes around 15 minutes to finish in debug mode. When I run the same tests in retail mode, it takes around 30 seconds. Is there anyway I can figure out what optimizations were done in the retail build?

Answer (score 2):

There's an option on the Project properties, Build tab: "Optimize code".  Try checking that then rebuilding the solution!

Hope that helps!

Comment: I checked and I actually do have this enabled.